# Get date/time at local timezone

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, timezone

[I *think* I've got this right but wanted to check. Doing timezone stuff does my head in sometimes!]

I have a table with an ordinary DATE column representing the desired delivery date (no time value). I can link it to another table which gives me the Australian state code. I want to determine whether the delivery time has arrived or not, keeping in mind that the server is running on a single time zone (e.g. Australia/Perth), to send a notification to the customer no earlier than 3pm their time.

So to determine what time (on the server) I should send the notification. If the customer record was created in Sydney, and I wait until 3pm, it will be too late, because 3pm in Perth is 5pm or 6pm in Sydney depending on daylight savings.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE custorders
  (delivery_date DATE
  ,state         VARCHAR2(3));

INSERT INTO custorders VALUES (DATE '2014-01-30', 'ACT');
INSERT INTO custorders VALUES (DATE '2014-01-30', 'NSW');
INSERT INTO custorders VALUES (DATE '2014-01-30', 'NT');
INSERT INTO custorders VALUES (DATE '2014-01-30', 'QLD');
INSERT INTO custorders VALUES (DATE '2014-01-30', 'SA');
INSERT INTO custorders VALUES (DATE '2014-01-30', 'TAS');
INSERT INTO custorders VALUES (DATE '2014-01-30', 'VIC');
INSERT INTO custorders VALUES (DATE '2014-01-30', 'WA');
```

Let's say that the server is running in Perth (WA) and we run the job at 12pm:

Expected Results:

```
STATE LOCAL_TIME
===== ==========
ACT   15:00
NSW   15:00
NT    13:30
QLD   14:00
SA    14:30
TAS   15:00
VIC   15:00
WA    12:00
```

I can then check if LOCAL_TIME is >= 15:00 before sending the notification to that customer.

Comment: Please note that I've only included the `delivery_date` column to illustrate the purpose of the table - I don't need the timezone for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have, seems to work - and it doesn't depend on the server running in any particular location (i.e. it assumes the server has its timezone set correctly):

```
SELECT state
      ,TO_CHAR(
         LOCALTIMESTAMP
         AT TIME ZONE
           CASE state
           WHEN 'QLD' THEN 'Australia/Queensland'
           WHEN 'ACT' THEN 'Australia/ACT'
           WHEN 'TAS' THEN 'Australia/Tasmania'
           WHEN 'NSW' THEN 'Australia/NSW'
           WHEN 'NT'  THEN 'Australia/Darwin'
           WHEN 'SA'  THEN 'Australia/Adelaide'
           WHEN 'WA'  THEN 'Australia/Perth'
           WHEN 'VIC' THEN 'Australia/Victoria'
           END
        ,'HH24:MI') AS local_time
FROM custorders;
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the job is running as Oracle SCHEDULER JOB, you should check the timezone of the job by this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ALL_SCHEDULER_GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE 
WHERE ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'DEFAULT_TIMEZONE'
```

Maybe it makes sense to migrate the date column to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` datatype. Or add a virtual column of this datatye and use this one.

```
ALTER TABLE custorders ADD (LOCAL_TIME TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
FROM_TZ(delivery_date,
           CASE state
           WHEN 'QLD' THEN 'Australia/Queensland'
           WHEN 'ACT' THEN 'Australia/ACT'
           WHEN 'TAS' THEN 'Australia/Tasmania'
           WHEN 'NSW' THEN 'Australia/NSW'
           WHEN 'NT'  THEN 'Australia/Darwin'
           WHEN 'SA'  THEN 'Australia/Adelaide'
           WHEN 'WA'  THEN 'Australia/Perth'
           WHEN 'VIC' THEN 'Australia/Victoria'
           END)
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the note about the scheduler job. WRT the date column: there's no need to change the date column, it only stores the date (no time) and the date doesn't change no matter where in Australia it was created.

Comment: Note that I want the time *now*, not the time from the delivery date.